# Trying to rule out astrology but something is wrong

Tags: statistics, chi-squared

I am trying to rule out a possible astrology effect on populations as a statistically insignificant effect but to no avail. I am using Pearson's Chi Square test on two distributions of sun signs from two different populations one of astronaut pilots and the other one of celebrities. Something must be wrong but I failed to find it, probably on the statistics side.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import ephem
from collections import Counter, namedtuple
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
models = pd.read_csv('models.csv', delimiter=',')
astronauts = pd.read_csv('astronauts.csv', delimiter=',')
models = models.sample(229)
astronauts = astronauts.sample(229)

sun = ephem.Sun()


def get_planet_constellation(planet, dataset):
    person_planet_constellation = []
    for person in dataset['Birth Date']:
        planet.compute(person)
        person_planet_constellation += [ephem.constellation(planet)[1]]
    return person_planet_constellation


def plot_bar_group(planet, data1, data2):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.bar(data1.keys(), data1.values(), alpha=0.5)
    plt.bar(data2.keys(), data2.values(), alpha=0.5)
    plt.legend(['astronauts', 'models'])
    ylabel = 'Percentages of ' + planet.name + ' in constellation'
    ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
    title = 'Histogram of ' + planet.name + ' in constellation by group'
    ax.set_title(title)
    plt.show()


astronaut_sun_constellation = Counter(
    get_planet_constellation(sun, astronauts))
model_sun_constellation = Counter(get_planet_constellation(sun, models))


plot_bar_group(sun, astronaut_sun_constellation, model_sun_constellation)

a = list(astronaut_sun_constellation.values())
b = list(model_sun_constellation.values())
s = np.array([a, b])

stat, p, dof, expected = stats.chi2_contingency(s)
print(stat, p, dof, expected)

prob = 0.95
critical = stats.chi2.ppf(prob, dof)
if abs(stat) >= critical:
    print('Dependent (reject H0)')
else:
    print('Independent (fail to reject H0)')

# interpret p-value
alpha = 1.0 - prob
if p <= alpha:
    print('Dependent (reject H0)')
else:
    print('Independent (fail to reject H0)')
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/w7rye6m5lbihjlh/astronauts.csv
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xlxanr0pxqtxcvv/models.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have eventually found the bug, it was on passing the counter as a list to the chisquare function, it must be sorted first, otherwise chisquare sees a major difference in the counters values. All astrology effects now are insignificant as expected at the level of 0.95